# Norm of position operator of quantum mechanics

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let the position operator be
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
\hat{x}: & L_2[a,b] & \to & L_2[a,b] \\
& f(x) & \mapsto & xf(x)
\end{array}\ .
$$

We can prove that this operator is bounded:
$$
||\hat{x}f(x)||_2 = ||xf(x)||_2 = \sqrt{\int_a^b |xf(x)|^2\ dx} = \sqrt{\int_a^b |x|^2|f(x)|^2\ dx}\ ,
$$
now define $M = \max\{|a|,|b|\}$ to bound that integral, and
$$
||\hat{x}f(x)||_2 \leq \sqrt{M^2 \int_a^b |f(x)|^2\ dx} = M ||f(x)||_2\ ,
$$
proving that $\hat{x}$ is a bounded operator.

However, this also makes a restriction on the norm of the operator, such that
$$
||\hat{x}|| \leq \max\{|a|,|b|\}\ .
$$
But I don't know how to calculate the norm from here. I know that three expressions can be used,
$$
||\hat{x}|| = \sup_{||f(x)||\leq 1} ||\hat{x}f(x)|| = \sup_{||f(x)|| = 1} ||\hat{x}f(x)|| = \sup_{||f(x)||\neq 0} \dfrac{||\hat{x}f(x)||}{||f(x)||}\ ,
$$
so I tried finding a $g(x)$ such that $||g(x)|| = 1$, and use it as a lower bound:
$$
||\hat{x}|| = \sup_{||f(x)|| = 1} ||\hat{x}f(x)|| \geq ||\hat{x}g(x)||\ ,
$$
but I didn't have too much success on this.

I would appreciate any help on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_n=\sqrt{n}1_{[b-1/n,b]}$ and note that for $n\geq\frac{1}{b-a}$, $f_n\in L^2([a,b])$ and $\|f_n\|_{L^2}=1$. Furthermore, we have
$$
\int_a^b x^2f_n(x)^2\textrm{d}x=n\int_{b-1/n}^b x^2\textrm{d}x=\frac{n}{3}(b^3-(b-1/n)^3)=\frac{n}{3}\left( \frac{1}{n^3}-3\frac{b}{n^2}+3\frac{b^2}{n}\right),
$$
which converges to $b^2$ as $n\to\infty$. Accordingly, $\|\hat{x}\|\geq |b|.$ Similarly, we can get $\|\hat{x}\|\geq |a|$ and thus, you get that $\|\hat{x}\|=\max\{|a|,|b|\}$.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for thew question but, what do you mean by the number 1 of the first definition? A function which is identical to 1 on all the given interval?

Comment: Yes, $1_A(x)$ is the function which is $1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ else. It's called the indicator function or characteristic function of $A$.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Thank you again!